# Prove $Im(T^*)=Ker(T)^\perp$

Tags: linear-algebra

Prove $Im(T^*)=Ker(T)^\perp$

Note: $T:V\rightarrow W$ then $T^*:W^*\rightarrow V^*$, where $W^*:\{f|f:W\rightarrow \mathbb{K}\}$

Note 2: $S^\perp=\{f\in V^*| f(v)=0\forall v\in S$

> My work: 
>   $Im(T^*)=\{f\in V^* :\exists g\in W^*|t^*(g)=f \}=\{f\in V^* :\exists g\in W^*|g\circ T=f \}=\{f\in V^* :\exists g\in W^*|(g\circ T)(v)=(f)(v)\forall v\in V \}=\{f\in V^* :\exists g\in W^*|(g(T))(v)=f(v)\forall v\in V \}=\{f\in V^* :\exists g\in W^*|(g(T(v))-f(v)=0\forall v\in V \}=\{f\in V^* :\exists g\in W^*|((g(T)-f)(v)=0\forall v\in V \}$

**Here i'm stuck. Can someone help me?**

I also need to prove this

$(Ker(T))=^\perp( Im(T^*))$

**Definition:**Let $V$ a $\mathbb{K}$-vector space and $S\subset V^*$ 

$^\perp (S)=\{v\in V |f(v)=0 \forall f\in S\}$

I was thinking in this:

> (I don't know if is equivalent to prove this) $$(Ker(T))^\perp=(^\perp( Im(T^*)))^\perp=Im(T^*)$$
>   If this is true, then this part of the exercise is solved.

Can someone help me?

Comment: If you can see them through duality, things will become a lot more easier, purely manipulating symbols may work though.

Answer (score 0):

The part $\text{Im}(T^{\ast})\subseteq\ker(T)^{\perp}$ is easy. Now we deal with the other direction. Fix a $v^{\ast}\in\ker(T)^{\perp}$. Let $S$ be the complement of $\ker(T)$ in $V$ and find a basis $B=\{b_{i}\}$ for $S$. Then $T(B)$ is linearly independent in $W$ and we define $w^{\ast}$ on $T(B)$ by setting $w^{\ast}(Tb_{i})=v^{\ast} b_{i}$ and we extend $w^{\ast}$ to the whole $W$, so $w^{\ast}\in W^{\ast}$. Now $v^{\ast}=T(w^{\ast})$ should be easy to check.

For the other question, only $^{\perp}(\text{Im}(T^{\ast}))\subseteq\ker(T)$ is hard to check: For $v\in$$^{\perp}(\text{Im}(T^{\ast}))$, assume that $w:=Tv\in W$ is nonzero, then we define $w^{\ast}$ in the following fashion. First, consider $\left<w\right>\subseteq W$, and we define $w^{\ast}(kw)=k$, and extend $w^{\ast}$ to the whole $W$, this can be done because $\{w\}$ is linearly independent, and we extend it to a basis for $W$, and set $w^{\ast}(b_{i})$ to be arbitrary value for the basis elements $b_{i}\ne w$. So now $w^{\ast}$ is such that $w^{\ast}(w)=1\ne 0$, but $T(w^{\ast})(v)=w^{\ast}(Tv)=0$ by the assumption that $v\in$$^{\perp}(\text{Im}(T^{\ast}))$, a contradiction, so $w$ must be zero, hence $v\in\ker(T)$.